# Set Question - is this possible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to have a set $Y$, such that:

$Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

$\forall y \in Y, \forall\alpha > 1, \alpha y \in Y$

$Y$ is non-empty and bounded.

Is such a set an impossibility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about $Y=\{(0,\dots,0)\}$?

Comment: Yeah, seems to work. Could you think of any other example?

Comment: No, it is the only such set.

Comment: @user191919 You can show that if a nonzero element exists in $Y$, then the set must be unbounded. It's not hard, try it!

Comment: If $y\ne0$, the $\{\alpha\,y:\alpha>1\}\subset Y$ is unbounded.